# What will * in bash do?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, chmod

My question is quite simple, if I am to enter these two line in OS X Terminal, what should happen?

```
xupengjunde-iMac:Shane Shane$ cd /Volumes/External
xupengjunde-iMac:External Shane$ sudo chmod -RN *
```

The R flag on chmod means recursive, changing permission for every file/folder.
The N flag means to remove ACL on files.

Now what about `*`? Will that mean all files on /Volumes/External or all files on my Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Bash expands `*` to the list of all files and directories in the current directory, except for the hidden ones (those starting with `.`). See [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) for the full explanation.

To answer your specific question: The command will change permissions on all files and directories inside `/Volumes/External` recursively. This means that any filesystems that are mounted in this directory will be changed recursively as well.

Comment: How is chmod rm... It will remove all ACL on those files...

Comment: Of course you're right, somehow I read `rm` instead of `chmod`...